# Replacing an existing element by another element in Set in Java

Tags: java, set

Is it possible replace an element of `java.util.Set` by another element? Given below a simple example.

```
Set<String> set=new LinkedHashSet<String>() {{
    add("A");
    add("B");
    add("C");
    add("D");
}};

if(set.contains("C")) {
    set.remove("C");
    set.add("E");
}

for(String str:set) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

This example first removes an element and adds another element afterwards. Doing so would add the element at the bottom of the `Set`.

It outputs after completion of the `foreach` loop as follows.

```
A
B
D
E
```

Is it somehow possible to just replace an existing element by another element retaining its original position so that it outputs like the following?

```
A
B
E
D
```

Comment: You need to use a list instead. Order of elements in a set is undefined.

Comment: Set is a Unordered Collection.

Comment: You could use a TreeSet to retain some kind of order.

Comment: @gtgaxiola Exactly :) I mean that.

Comment: In this variant (LinkedHashSet) Set is ordered: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I know you know...sometimes we all get Layer8 problems except Jon Skeet...

Comment: Use LinkedList and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#set(int,%20E)

Comment: @DmitryTsechoev: Not flexible enough to be of any use though.

Comment: I cannot use a `List`. This `LinkedHashSet` is backed by a user shopping basket in which the order in which the items are added is important and it should retain and the list must not contain duplicate products (element replacement is required, when items are added to the cart from a user wishlist with different quantity values in some or all products. New quantity values should be reflected from the cart).

Comment: @BheshGurung, you are right.

Comment: @Seb : A `TreeSet` sorts items in natural order or according to the comparator given. In this case, the set is expected to maintain its order in which the elements are added.

Answer (score 1):

No. `LinkedHashSet.add` is inherited from [`HashSet.add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add-E-). Using it on a `LinkedHashSet` will add the element at the end of the underlying linked list.

Answer (score 1):

As all the answers above you cannot do that with Set. You can achieve this by adding the set to a list, then do operation and then back to set. But that is very expensive. Alternatively If you are particular about this kind of implementation you can use [Apache Commons ListOrderedSet](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/set/ListOrderedSet.html). Please note that as far as I know this doesn't support generics. So either you'll have to put extra care on type safety or else you could do explicit casting. Example

```
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.commons.collections.set.ListOrderedSet;

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Set<String> set = new ListOrderedSet();
        set.add("A");
        set.add("B");
        set.add("C");
        set.add("D");

        System.out.println(set); // Prints [A, B, C, D]
        int indexToRemove = ((ListOrderedSet) set).indexOf("C");
        if (indexToRemove != -1) {
            set.remove("C");
            ((ListOrderedSet) set).add(indexToRemove, "E");
        }
        System.out.println(set); // Prints [A, B, E, D]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    set.add("A");
    set.add("B");
    set.add("C");
    set.add("D");
    System.out.println(set);

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.addAll(0, set);
System.out.println(list);

if(list.contains("C")){
       int i = list.indexOf("C");
       list.add(i, "E");
       list.remove("C");
}

set.removeAll(set);
//System.out.println(list);
//System.out.println(set);
set.addAll(list);
System.out.println(set);
}
```

with this solution you have to use unwanted List :(

```
output :[A,B,E,D]
```